# Monitor Java Application to get list of accessed files

Tags: java, monitor

i am working with a complex application and like to know which files it creates and accesses. Is there a way to monitor the application or the jvm it runs with to get this information?

EDIT: i am working with windows 7

matthias

Comment: Which OS you're using? You may need some OS specific external application. For example on Windows Process Explorer and inotify-tools on Linux.

Comment: Some profilers such a YourKit do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try JConsole for this:
[Using JConsole to Monitor Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html)